# Redirect 'complete' in bash functions and alias

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, auto-completion, functions

**tl;dr: Is there a way to use an existing auto completion function to also auto complete arguments to an alias or short function.**

Auto completion in bash is great but does not mix well with aliases and utility functions.

For example, let us say I often call an executable `myexec` with some arguments always there:

```
myexec --arg1=val1 --arg2 foo
myexec --arg1=val1 --arg2 bar
myexec --arg1=val1 --arg2 foobaz
...
```

To make my life easier I can create an alias: `alias myalias='myexec --arg1=val1 --arg2'`, but then I will lose order completion for the arguments that varies from time to time (`foo`, `bar`, etc.)

### Problem 1: Alias

Is there a way where I can make the auto completion on `myalias` act as though I have written `myexec --arg1=val1 --arg2`, that is, these two commands should produce the same output:

```
# Theese should provide identical completion
myalias foo[tab]
myexec --arg1=val1 --arg2 foo[tab]
```

### Problem 2: Function

Is there a way to do the same for function, for example:

```
function myfun {
  cd ../..
  myexec --arg1=val1 --arg2 $@
  cd some/dir
}
# Theese should provide identical completion
myfun foo[tab]
myexec --arg1=val1 --arg2 foo[tab]
```

---

I have taking a look at [this great introduction](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.ch/2011/04/writing-your-own-bash-completion.html) and on the [man page](http://ss64.com/osx/complete.html), but I do not have experience enough to derive a solution from that.

Thanks a bunch for your help `:)`

Comment: Or switch to `zsh`. `zsh` completes with aliases just fine.